# Updateable archive format which includes file permission

Tags: backup

I know there are similar questions around, but none made me happy:

Is there a console based file archiving / compression tool, which saves Linux file permissions and is also able to update an existing archive (adding new/changed files) without full extraction and re-compression? Like 7zip, but with file permissions?

Comment: tar cannot update compressed archives... So using tar this way would require to zip files before sending them to the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Info-ZIP [`zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zip.1.html) and [`unzip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/unzip.1.html) utilities, available on Debian, Ubuntu, and many other Linux systems, preserve timestamps, owner and group IDs, and file mode bits.

- `zip` stores them by default.
- `unzip` restores timestamps and file mode bits by default, except setuid and setgid bits. To restore owner and group IDs use `unzip -X`, and to restore setuid and setgid bits use `unzip -KX`.
- Use `zipinfo` to list the file modes.

Comment: Nice. As the man page did not mention 'permissions' (but instead calls it 'protection', as I see now) I was completely not aware of it. Although changing file permissions without changing the content of a file will not cause any updates in the archive this will do it perfectly for my use case. Thanks.